# Woocommerce email debugger issue

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I have found a little debugger for woocommerce email (http://enru.co.uk/2014/02/17/testing-woocommerce-emails/)

It works fine, except for one thing: ***I want ot use this for debug purpose only***, and at the moment, everytime i open an email the email is sent as well. Can i change the code so that i can view the email without actually send it?

My code is this:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: WC_Email_Preview
*/
?>

<?php

// include WordPress' wp-load
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wp-load.php");

/*// verbose errors
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);*/

$order_id = "4452";
$email_class = $_REQUEST['email'];

if ($email_class == null) {
    $email_class = 'WC_Email_Customer_Invoice';
}

if (!isset ($order_id)) {
    global $wpdb;
    $latestOrderID = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT max(ID) as ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'shop_order';", OBJECT);
    $order_id = $latestOrderID[0]->ID;
};

$wc_emails = new WC_Emails();
$emails = $wc_emails->get_emails();

/*$new_email = $emails[$email_class];*/
$new_email->trigger($order_id);
echo $new_email->get_content();
return;
?>
```

The problem is, i tryed to add **return** at the end of the code to avoid the email to be sent, but it didn't work. **What i have to change to disable the send function?**

thanks

Comment: Maybe you should return before you do "echo $new_email->get_content()"?

Comment: @FlorianGerhardt no, even if I return  before "echo $new_email->get_content()" the email is still sent

Comment: Maybe before the "$new_email->trigger(...)" then?

Comment: The problem is in the $new_email->trigger(...). This triggers the email to be generated and after that, to be sent. Problem is, i don't know how and what to change in this. I tried to set the recipient to null before the trigger, but it changes after the trigger so i don't know what to do to hook into that function without break the default email behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i found a way to do that.

Basically i changed `trigger()` function to `debugEmail()`, and inside the `class-wc-email-customer-invoice.php` file, copied the `trigger()` into `debugEmail()` and removed the this line to avoid the send of the email:

```
$this->send( $this->get_recipient(), $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), $this->get_attachments() );
```